# Scheduling a query to run on a schedule that exports a CSV in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Good morning,

I am rather new to SQL and I've scoured the internet to try to find a solution to my issue to no avail. I've tried creating procedures, jobs, programs, credentials and schedules through the SQL Developer interface and modifying them as instructed by every article I could find on the subject and I can't seem to get this working.

I'd like to run the following SQL Script every 30 minutes from 0600 to 1700 Mon-Friday, so that it exports a CSV file every 30 minutes.

When I execute the script in SQL developer, it queries the database and saves the file just as intended, but no matter how many times I've tried to get it working on a schedule I can't seem to get t right.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
SPOOL C:\Users\X\Documents\SQL\Uploads\X.CSV
SET SQLFORMAT CSV


    SELECT

    NAME_OF_PERSON

    FROM DATABASE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In versions lower than 12c, Oracle's `DBMS_JOB` and/or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` will schedule execution of a stored procedure. It can create a file, but you'll have to use `UTL_FILE` package to do that, not `SPOOL`.

As you're on Oracle 12c, its `DBMS_SCHEDULER` now offers a new job type - `SQL_SCRIPT`,  which lets you schedule a .SQL script. It means that code you posted should be stored as a file. I can't create an example on my 11gXE, but here's a link to **ORACLE-BASE** site: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/scheduler-enhancements-12cr1 and script copied from it which shows how to do that:

```
CONN test/test@pdb1

-- Create a job with a SQL*Plus script defined in-line,
-- including an explicit connect.
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_job_name VARCHAR2(30);
  l_script   VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  l_job_name := DBMS_SCHEDULER.generate_job_name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('JOB_NAME=' || l_job_name);

  -- Notice the explicit database connection in the script.
  l_script := 'CONN test/test@pdb1
SPOOL /tmp/test.lst
SELECT SYSDATE, USER FROM dual;
SPOOL OFF';

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
    job_name        => l_job_name,
    job_type        => 'SQL_SCRIPT',
    job_action      => l_script,
    credential_name => 'oracle_ol6_121',
    enabled         => TRUE
  );
END;
/
```

Alternatively, you could use your operating system's scheduling program (Task Scheduler on MS Windows) and tell it to run a .BAT script which would establish SQL*Plus connection and run a .SQL script which contains `SPOOL` command and that `SELECT` statement.

Forgot to say: I wouldn't involve SQL Developer into that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SQLcl with Oracle 12c.

1) Create .sql file with your spool settings, export location and sql commands

2) Create a .bat file with the SQLcl command:

```
'>>cd C:\oracle\product\64bit_12.1.0.2client\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin  <--or wherever your sql.exe file is-->

'>>SQL username/password@server:port/pid @C:/users/.../myjob.sql
```

3) Create a basic job in Windows Task Scheduler to trigger the .bat file